# Unsupported event loop group type: NioEventLoopGroup using pgjdbc-ng

Tags: java, postgresql

After [reviewing](https://www.openmakesoftware.com/postgresql-listen-notify-events-example/) by Steve Taylor
I have tried to use it in my rest API but I have not managed to create the connection with my database, I have tried to create an instance of the `ListenNotify` class in the main thread and in secondary threads without achieving good result, please I could use it a little of help.

```
package com.curu.open.rest.notifications.PostgresChanel;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.impossibl.postgres.api.jdbc.PGConnection;
import com.impossibl.postgres.api.jdbc.PGNotificationListener;
import com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource;

public class ListenNotify {
  // Database connection
  PGConnection connection;

  public ListenNotify() {
    // Create the listener callback
    PGNotificationListener listener = new PGNotificationListener() {
      @Override
      public void notification(int processId, String channelName, String payload) {
        System.out.println("/channels/" + channelName + " " + payload);
      }
    };
    try {
      PGDataSource dataSource = new PGDataSource();
      dataSource.setHost("localhost");
      dataSource.setPort(5432);
      dataSource.setDatabaseName("test");
      dataSource.setUser("postgres");
      dataSource.setPassword("postgres");
      // Log into the db
      connection = (PGConnection) dataSource.getConnection();
      // add the callback listener created earlier to the connection
      connection.addNotificationListener(listener);
      // Tell Postgres to send NOTIFY q_event to our connection and listener
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      statement.execute("LISTEN my_event");
      statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

> com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: 
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported event loop group type: 
>       NioEventLoopGroup at    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ErrorUtils.makeSQLException(ErrorUtils.java:137)
>     at
>   com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:212)
>     at
>   com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.AbstractDataSource.createConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:137)
>     at
>   com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:71)
>     at
>   com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:63)
>     at
>   com.curu.open.rest.notifications.PostgresChanel.ListenNotify.(ListenNotify.java:58)
>     at
>   com.curu.open.NotificationDispacherTimerTask.run(NotificationDispacherTimerTask.java:29)
>     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: How are you adding the pgjdbc-ng dependency?

Comment: I added pgjdbc-ng 0.8.1 and postgresql-42.2.5  to my maven repository. I need to do something else? <dependency>
        <groupId>com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng</groupId>
        <artifactId>pgjdbc-ng</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
     </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

However you are executing the program, the transitive dependencies of the `pgjdbc-ng` are not getting added to your classpath.

One solution is to use the the uber jar that includes all dependencies package in one jar.

To use the uber jar via Maven you need to add the "all" classifier to the dependency specification, as in

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.impossibl.pgjdb-ng</groupId>
  <artifactId>pgjdb-ng</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2</version>
  <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively you can manually download the uber jar and add it to your class path. More information is available in the "Manual Download" section of the [User Guide](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-deps)

*NOTE*: Using the uber jar shouldn't be necessary if you are executing your program in a way that includes Maven's transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks but my error after add <classifier>all</classifier>  tag in my com.impossibl.pgjdb-ng dependency is this :Could not resolve dependencies for project com.curu:rest:war:1.2: Could not find artifact com.impossibl.pgjdb-ng:pgjdb-ng:jar:all:0.8.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: @RafaelBelloLara I believe your setup for maven is incorrect. I am quite certain the "all" uber jar is in central; you can see it here (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/pgjdbc-ng/0.8.2). Also, I copied the coordinates in my answer from a test project that properly locates the "all" uber jar.

Answer (score 0):

Like @kdubb said "However you are executing the program, the transitive dependencies of the pgjdbc-ng are not getting added to your classpath."

I am using graddle and adding the dependencies like so:

```
compileOnly "com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng:pgjdbc-ng:0.8.9"
```

I was getting a bunch of *ClassNotFoundException*'s

When you declare a dependency using **compileOnly**, it includes only the direct dependency in your project's classpath, but it excludes the transitive dependencies. However declaring a dependency using **implementation**, not only includes the direct dependencies but also all of its transitive ones.